# How to get two packages to handle the same file extension

Tags: meteor, isobuild

I would like to know how to get two packages to compile the same file extension.

I am writing a package that compiles `.jsx` by looking for certain strings and replacing them. Inside this plugin, I am using `isobuild:compiler-plugin@1.0.0`:

```
Plugin.registerCompiler({
  extensions: ['jsx']
}, function () {
  ...
});
```

The problem is that I cannot use this with mdg's `jsx` package because that package is also trying to compile `.jsx`.

Meteor gives me:

```
While determining active plugins:
error: conflict: two packages included in the app (jsx and my-plugin) are both trying to handle *.jsx
```

Ideally, I would like `jsx` plugin to compile the `.jsx` files first, and then my plugin to compile them again. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Or can someone point me to any other directions?

Comment: have you tried something like `.my.jsx` as an extension? I *think* that works. I'm not sure how you would get the jsx plugin to compile the result of your compilation (unless you can somehow rename the files), but at least you might be able to have two separate plugins compile those files.